# How to explode 2 word to same out put?

Tags: php, explode

How to apply explode to explode

co.uk   ======> co     uk

.co.uk  ======> co     uk

first code it's ok , it's will explode co.uk =====> co   uk

```
<?php
$data = "co.uk";
list($tld, $tld_sub) = explode(".", $data);
echo $tld;
echo "<br>";
echo $tld_sub;
?>
```

But for use .co.uk ,it's not ok ?

```
<?php
$data = ".co.uk";
list($tld, $tld_sub) = explode(".", $data);
echo $tld;
echo "<br>";
echo $tld_sub;
?>
```

How can i apply ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably be better off stripping any dot characters first:

```
list($tld, $tld_sub) = explode('.', trim($data, '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one using foreach

```
<?php
$data = ".co.uk";
$data = explode(".", $data);
foreach($data as $value)
{
echo $value.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php
$data = ".co.uk";
$list = array_filter(explode(".", $data));
$tld = $list[1];
$tld_sub = $list[2];
echo $tld;
echo "<br>";
echo $tld_sub;
?>
```